# Is it possible to have validation in xtext language alone

Tags: xtext

We are trying to have validations for a certain language ,but what we are trying is to write the skeltons of language and validation too in xtext (not using xtend at all )
Is it possible to have validation in xtext language alone i.e.., not using xtend.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by validation in Xtext? Do you mean in Java?

Comment: Consider this particular example    Ex:class.method_name()  {test,test1,test(test,test2,test3)},{test,test1,test(test,test2,test3)},{test,test1,test(test,test2,test3)}  .   This is basic example iin magik language .so now we are writing code for this validation to check any comma(,) , braces (   "("   ," )  ") are missing and tring to validate them .Is it possible to have such high level validation written in xtext language      alone

Comment: Similar example  :    an_f << o.get_field(:internal_pin)
map_rec << an_f.archive_mapping({171971, "voltage", True,0 })
map_rec.archive_values({{"11kV", :internal_pin_hv},
                        {"132kV", :internal_pin_ehv},
                        {"LV", :internal_pin_lv}})
an_f << o.get_field(:external_pin)
map_rec << an_f.archive_mapping({171973, "voltage", True,0 })
map_rec.archive_values({{"11kV", :external_pin_hv},
                        {"132kV", :external_pin_ehv},
                        {"LV", :external_pin_lv}})

Comment: we are trying to validate each comma and brace ,to some extend its fine but going ddeeper and deeper it is not even compiling .So is it correct approach what we are following (That is not using xtend language )

Comment: I see you want to get syntactical errors during parsing instead of writing validation checks. Please update your question with a readable example and relevant part of your grammar.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question based on these rules.

Comment: Here is my problem, I need to validate this sample which is recursive (repetative). Here is the example {   this ,is ,my ,problem ,{ this ,is ,my ,problem } } .This sample repeats both in and out. And for this, my logic is  
Validdata:
 (name=ID','|INT','|STRING',')*
 (name=ID|INT|STRING)  ; 
Bracesvalid:
( '{' Validdata '},'  )*
( '{' Validdata '}'  )  
This code allow me to have this side by side ,but not into the barces. Ex: {   this ,is ,my ,problem }, {   this ,is ,my ,problem }
But into the braces it is not allowed.How to get rid of this problem with solution.Thank you in advance

Comment: will xtext support recursive functionality  ?

Comment: Which language are you validating?

Comment: we are validating for the magik language

Answer (score 0):

Your Xtext grammar should be recursive, something like that:

```
Model:
    value=Data;

Data:
    DataSequence;

DataSequence returns Data:
    PrimaryData (=> ',' {DataSequence.values+=current} values+=PrimaryData (',' values+=PrimaryData)*)?;

PrimaryData returns Data:
    CompositeData |
    ClassData |
    Identifier |
    StringLiteral |
    NumberLiteral;

ClassData returns Data:
    {ClassData} 'class' name=ID;

CompositeData returns Data:
    {CompositeData} '{' value=Data '}';

Identifier returns Data:
    {Identifier} name=ID;

StringLiteral returns Data:
    {StringLiteral} value=STRING;

NumberLiteral returns Data:
    {NumberLiteral} value=INT;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info

Comment: @PrakashSurya does it answer your question? please don't forget to mark the answer then

Comment: Thank you Anton Kosyakov . The answer you  provided help me a lot ,but i need some data in that syntax to be not validated,As per your code it validates everything in it ,but some not be validated such as some keywords like _class ,_self in my language .I had similar 30 keywords .So can you help me out of this .Here is example   _class hai ,test, _class Bye

Comment: I've added `ClassData` rule to show how to handle it. Does it answer your question?

Comment: As per the code given by you ,the name=ID after the "class"  is going to be mandatory .But we want it optional with disturbing the validation you provided.I just wrote 'class'  (name=ID)* but is violating the previous conditions

Comment: Can you suggest how to make ID in above code optional without violating previous validation